# How does a current mirror work?

Tags: analog, bjt, ltspice

I'm trying to understand how current mirrors work.

In the text book *Microelectronics* by Jacob Millman, section 3-11, example 3-8, there is a picture of a current mirror:
[image: Current Mirror]

They said if we consider \$V_{BE}\$ of these two transistors to be the same (`0.7 V`) then \$I_B\$ and \$I_C\$ of these 2 transistors are equal.

**Question 1:**

This statement confuse me. I think the correct statement should be "The maximum allowable \$I_C\$ of `Q2` is equal to `Q1`'s \$I_C\$", because the base current \$I_B\$ of a transistor is only a "valve" for the current, it decides the maximum current, but the actual current should be decided by the load. So when they said the two \$I_C\$s are the same, are they refering to the maximum of `Q2`'s \$I_C\$?

**Question 2:**

When I simulate this circuit in LTspice, the result is strange:

[image: LTspice Schematic]

[image: Ib Plot 1]

[image: Ib Plot 2]

The \$I_B\$ currents of the two transistors aren't the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the LTspice schematic, \$Q_2\$ is diode-connected. It observes its collector current and generates a base-emitter voltage. This base-emitter voltage is then observed by \$Q_1\$, which sets its collector current, accordingly. As long as the collector load for \$Q_1\$ doesn't drop too much voltage (and discounting the Early Effect for now), then \$Q_1\$'s collector current will match \$Q_2\$'s collector current. Keep in mind that the resistor setting the current for \$Q_2\$ supplies not only the collector current for \$Q_2\$, but also **both** base currents for both BJTs.

Comment: your musings for Q1 would be correct if the transistor was saturated, low VCE, then the load would determine the current. However, it's working linearly, VCE >> VCEsat, so the transistor defines the current.

Comment: If you make R1=500 Ohm then it is ok ... current are "equal" each other ...

Comment: @periblepsis what do you mean by "diode connected" ? Is that means the collector and the base are connected?
I think the IC and IB of Q2 are not related to Q1's opetation, so we can consider them to be constant.
You said: "As long as the collector load for Q1 doesn't drop too much voltage then Q1's collector current will match Q2's collector current."  Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Neil_UK But i think the external load still affect the current greatly though. If there is a resistor in the emitter of the output transistor then maybe, but in the drawing there is no resistor in the emitter. Like Wildlar current source, there is a resistor in the emitter of the output transistor.

Comment: @Antonio51 CAn you explain how you reach that value?

Comment: @ngquan Yes, connecting collector to base directly makes it 'diode-connected.' You can think of it as a certain kind of diode and, in fact, that's how you know *about* what current is being set by your \$R_1\$. Your current in \$R_1\$ is \$\frac{12\:\text{V}-V_{_\text{BE}}}{R_1=100\:\Omega}\approx 110\:\text{mA}\$. \$Q_1\$ would like to copy that. But it can't as \$50\:\Omega\cdot 110\:\text{mA}=5.5\:\text{V}\$ and the supply voltage on that side is too low to allow that (or \$R_2\$ is too large, etc.) So the current mirror ***isn't*** a current mirror then.

Comment: @periblepsis I agree on the current of R1. But i think "in theory", what Q1 copies isn't I(R1) but IC(Q2), because IB(Q1) = IB(Q2). When i use ltspice, the 2 IBs and the 2 ICs are not equal. Maybe the 2 ICs are not equal, but the 2 IBs should be equal right?

Comment: @ngquan You are thinking too simply. The BJT model is more complex. There is an Early Effect. (There are, in fact, a great many effects which LTspice accounts for but your brain doesn't.) Do you know how to account for the Early Effect? Or how to remove its effect when running LTspice? Are you aware of the Wilson mirror and what it does and why? The point of all this is that there is a primary behavior, but there are secondary behaviors. If you expect to see ***exact*** matches, then you are likely going to be saddened by reality.

Comment: @ngquan The calculus of periblepsis is just done and it is ok. See also my answer.

Comment: @periblepsis I want to make this clear: Does the IC(Q1) copy IC(Q2) or I(R1)? Because in the simulation by Antonio below, the IC(R1) and IC(Q1) seem to be closer.

Comment: @ngquan I can't directly answer that question with yes or no. It's like asking "When was the last time you beat your kid?" It makes assumptions not in evidence. It's possible to force LTspice to simplify the BJT model and then to account for enough of the ancillary details (which you don't appear to know about) in a mathematical equation that will then produce a theoretical result that will be very close to what LTspice shows. But you need to (1) simplify the model for LTspice and (2) account for details you aren't accounting for in your theory side math. If you do BOTH, then much closer.

Comment: @ngquan And no, you are still not thinking about this well. But I don't blame you, at all. Same place I was at, back when. We all go through this process in some fashion.

Comment: @ngquan Are you looking for a mathematical approach? I can provide it. Or hand-waving? This discussion can go on for a while.

Comment: @ngquan [This may help you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0M75.png) Please take careful note about the collector currents of both BJTs!!! I think you see that it is possible to compute nearly exact results. The point here is that you just need to learn a few more details, is all. The theory is robust and accurate. You need to catch up. That's all.

Comment: @periblepsis Thank you

Comment: @ngquan Note that I had to account for ***two*** base currents when setting the resistor value. (See the last equation to find that fact.) I also needed to estimate the VBE for the BJT. You can see that equation both in the last equation as well as stated in comments earlier. As long as the BJTs are in active mode (not saturated out), it works pretty well. This is why it is found in so many places in opamps, for example. The mirror is wonderful in the sense that the temperature-dependent parts are mostly removed out so the mirror works over a wide temperature range! Do study it!!!

Comment: @ngquan There are some BJT structures that are just pure poetry. The differential pair, the cascode pair and the current mirror are some of these. (Michael Wyatt's `Cascode Peaking Current Source` is another piece of wonder for me.) The Gilbert cell and the MC1496 structures are more wonder for me. Just FYI. (Gilbert died a few years ago. Sweet man. I went to his funeral.)

Comment: @periblepsis Thank you very much. I will look into your model more. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ngquan Truly. Best wishes from me!! Keep up the good work. I'll add a +1 just to help out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you get ... as @periblepsis pointed out ...

[image]

You can see that "current mirror" if my R2 > 250 Ohms ...

Comment: So the current mirror can only use for small value current? How do you choose values for R2 and R1?

Comment: Yes. My R2 must be greater then my R1 (100 Ohm) x V2/V1 > 240 Ohm.

Comment: Thanks, is this because you have to set up so that the output circuit CAN produce the current you want to mirror? (V1/R1 > V2/R2)

Comment: Right. It should be so.

Answer (score 6):

The book's statement is accurate enough. They imply that if these two transistors are closely matched in behaviour, with similar \$\beta\$, and similar relationship between \$V_{BE}\$ and \$I_B\$, then since their \$V_{BE}\$ is the same, then their base currents \$I_B\$ are also equal.

It then follows that \$I_C = \beta I_B\$ will be the same for both transistors, ***but only if that condition is possible in the first place***.

Your statements confuse me, I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. I would say that the "master" side current, that is collector current in Q2, is determined almost exclusively by the power supply potential (+12V) on the left and the collector resistor R1. The voltage across R1 is only 0.7V less than 12V (due to Q2 behaving like a diode), leaving almost the whole supply across R1, allowing you to set any current you want there by varying R1.

On the slave side, Q1, you must ensure that the power supply on that side, and collector resistance R2 on that side permit the same current there too. Being a current source, Q1's collector potential will vary anywhere between +5V and near 0V, in compliance, but that's all the variation it can do. If you ask for a current greater than achievable by 5V across 50Ω, Q1 will saturate, no longer able  to comply.

Your simulation doesn't work because Q1 (right) is saturated.

Q2 is passing *about* \$\frac{12V}{100\Omega} = 120mA\$. The maximum current that could ever flow down the right-hand path, via Q1, is \$\frac{5V}{50\Omega}=100mA\$.

This mirror can't work if the "slave" side is *incapable* of achieving whatever "master" side current is passing. In this case Q1's collector current is maxed out at 100mA, with collector potential close to zero. In other words Q1 is saturated.

If you wish to examine base currents during successful mirroring, you must not ask for more current in Q1 than is possible. For example, reduce current on the left, by increasing R1 to 200Ω, which will cut Q2's collector current in half, to about 60mA. That's a current that the right had side *can* deal with, which would develop \$60mA \times 50\Omega = 3V\$ across R2. That places the collector of R2 at about \$5V-3V=+2V\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYtUJk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So it only mirror the maximum current IC right? And the voltage source needs to be able to supply that current, it will make IC max out according to what set by the Q1's IC. Do i get that right?

Comment: @ngquan It mirrors ***up to*** the maximum current possible on the slave side. In your case that maximum is nearly \$\frac{5V}{50\Omega}=100mA\$. You can set any current you like on the left, master side, between 0 and 100mA, the the right side will have that same/similar amount of collector current. Setting more than 100mA on the master side will saturate Q1, and mirroring fails.

Comment: @ngquan If that's what you meant, then yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

To understand a bipolar transistor current mirror, it is easiest to consider that the collector current is controlled by the base-emitter *voltage* (via an exponential relationship). Consider also that in normal bias, the base current is much less than the collector (or emitter) current.

A secondary factor is that collector current isn't *exclusively* controlled by VBE, but that there is a slight dependence on collector-emitter voltage (VCE) -- that dependency is the *Early voltage*.

Now, in your circuit, when IR is supplied, most of it flows in Q1's collector, but a small amount flows in the bases. Given the (exponential) relationship between IC and VBE, this results in VBE resolving to a value that depends on (amongst other things) the log() of the collector current.

**Q2 receives the same VBE, so its collector current (neglecting Early effects) is the same as Q1.**

Note that these collector currents are not identical to the input current -- IR -- because some (small) amount is consumed by the base currents.

An impact of the Early effect is that *base* current also depends on collector voltage (you can look on it as beta depending on VCE). The magnitude of this effect depends on the construction of the device.

By thinking this way, you can see that it is possible to add additional 'Q2' devices (with separate collectors) and get multiple outputs. A MOS current mirror also behaves this way - drain current is controlled by gate voltage.

Thinking of BJTs being controlled by base current (and having a parameter beta)is not really how those devices work -- in the physics, it is VBE that controls the behavior, and (base) current is a consequence of that. However it can be convenient, and beta may appear reasonably constant over a wide range of operating conditions, and can be a useful consideration.

Answer (score 3):

> The maximum allowable IC of Q2 is equal to Q1's IC

Not really. If Q2 saturates, its base will start hogging current from the diode-connected Q1.

So, Q2 needs to be connected so that it can *always* sink the same current as Q1 without saturating. Once it saturates, the whole thing stops working.

I.e. if you don't let enough current flow through Q2 to unsaturate it, the mirror doesn't work, and the voltage across the Q1 diode is much lower than it should be.

Recall that there can be **multiple** Q2's connected in parallel to the same base reference diode, each of them sinking a copy of Q1's current into a different part of the circuit. If just *one* of them saturates, the mirroring reference transfers from Q1 to the saturated transistor. In fact, out of all the transistors in a multi-output current source, it is always the one with lowest emitter current density takes over being a reference for other outputs.

> The IB currents of the two transistors aren't the same.

They generally won't be, unless the collector potentials are identical. In most cases, Q2's collector will be quite a bit higher than Q1's collector.

---

There is another problem easy to overlook with current mirrors when simulating them in SPICE: thermal runaway. Discrete current mirrors need very good thermal coupling between transistors. Separate TO-92 devices on a breadboard will run away somewhere around 0.1A emitter current, and will perform rather poorly above 1mA due to thermal drift.

Even for just a few mA, good thermal coupling requires TO-126 packages touching back-to-back. With more than two transistors, a copper block is needed to couple them, although for currents below 10mA a stack of those transistors, with thermal paste between them, and a screw pinching them together, does the job. At 0.1A mirror currents, TO-220 packages back-to-back on a copper heatsink work well. For more than 2 packages, a copper block is needed.

More than two transistors are needed when multiple outputs are required and/or when different emitter current densities have to be emulated by paralleling emitters.

Answer (score 1):

## Ideas versus implementations

Both are equally important, but the proper sequence is to reveal the most general, basic, fundamental ideas first, and only then to attack the imperfections and discuss the details of specific implementations. With my answer I will try to show that.

Years ago I wrote a [story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/How_to_Reverse_Current_Direction) where I did this imaginary, and then my students and I [implemented it](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Group_67b#Lab_3:_Transistor_circuits_(%22inventing%22_a_BJT_current_mirror)) in the lab. I have now animated it with CircuitLab simulations to make it more attractive and convincing.

## Basic ideas

### Heterogeneous + heterogeneous = homogeneous

A current mirror consists of two cascaded "mirror" converters with heterogeneous inputs and outputs - *current-to-voltage* and *voltage-to-current*. The result is a *current-to-current* converter (amplifier, follower or attenuator). Figuratively speaking, the input and output current are connected by an intermediate voltage.

The opposite is also possible - *voltage-to-current* and *current-to-voltage* converter cascaded. As a result, a *voltage-to-voltage* converter (amplifier, follower or attenuator) is obtained where the input and output voltages are connected by an intermediate current. An example of this is an op-amp inverting amplifier.

### Nonlinear + nonlinear = linear

The genius of this configuration is that the characteristics of the individual converters are irrelevant; we just want them to be reversed ("mirrored"). If they are non-linear (in the particular case, a log and antilog converter), their non-linearities are destroyed and in general a linear converter is obtained.

So the great idea of the current mirror is ***to connect in series (cascade) two mutually inverse non-linear converters, resulting in a linear converter***.

### Reversed converter

But usually we have converters of only one type - *voltage-to-current* (transconductance); these are transistors. In contrast to 2-terminal diodes, they are *one-way converters* (we cannot swap their input and output). Then we apply the next brilliant idea of the current mirror - ***reverse the converter using the principle of negative feedback. To do this, we force it to set its input value to match the output value. As a result, the output becomes an input and the input becomes an output***.

### Reversed current direction

The two cascaded converters are connected through voltages that are referenced (joined) to the same supply rail. So the current mirror input and output can only be both sinking or both sourcing. This means that whether we want it or not, the current mirror inverts the current direction (if it was not inverting, it would have a sinking input and a sourcing output).

## Building the circuit

I propose to follow the evolution of the current mirror step by step using CircuitLab experiments. As an input current source, we can use a voltage source Vin with a resistor R in series. It is quite a good current source because the collector voltage of the input transistor is very small (around 700 mV) and does not significantly affect the current magnitude.

### Reversing the input transistor

**Trying to drive the collector...** Although we know the result, let's still try to swap the input and output of a transistor (ie, to inject an input current into the collector and take the base voltage as the output).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOOGDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The result matches our expectations - despite our best efforts to "blow" current into the transistor, it resists us staying *off*. No collector current flows and there is no base voltage.

[image: STEP 1]

**... with fixed base voltage...** Then let's apply some voltage to the base to make it pass current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLmYdR.png)</sup>

However, we see that instead of remaining constant, the collector voltage follows the changes of the input voltage (increases at the same rate). Ah... the transistor works as a current source which creates a constant voltage drop of 5 V across the resistor so its collector voltage "moves" up.

[image: STEP 2]

**... with adjusted base voltage**. So we have to stop it. For this purpose, we begin increasing the base voltage Vvar, and the collector voltage Vout begins decreasing. We stop when the two voltages equalize (at 718.6 mV, according to the schematic below).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi9n8I.png)</sup>

The result satisfies us.

[image: STEP 3]

**Connecting the collector to the base.** We notice that the two voltages "move" against each other and finally "meet" at the equilibrium point. Hmm, this "smells" like negative feedback that we manually implement. Let's then make the transistor do it. For this purpose, we connect its output (collector) to its input (base)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Bpez.png)</sup>

**Removing Vvar** ... and of course, finally remove the base voltage source Vvar.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkavHt.png)</sup>

Now the transistor adjusts its Vb voltage to pass the collector current supplied to it by the input source.

[image: STEP 4]

It varies slightly like the voltage across a diode.

### "Normal transistor"

Then this "output" voltage can be applied as an input Vbe voltage to a "normal" (not inversed) transistor Q2 to convert it to another current Iout = Iin. So Q2 acts as an *antilog voltage-to-current converter*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvQFH1.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 5]

### Cascaded transistors

In this way, we obtained a "mirror" copy of the flowing in input current where the output current has the same magnitude but an opposite direction (again flowing in instead of flowing out).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLsu7d.png)</sup>

As we can see from the graph below, the two cascaded nonlinear converters really form a linear converter.

[image: STEP 6]

### Comparison

Finally, it is interesting to compare this active diode current mirror with such made by ordinary diodes.

**Base-emitter junction**. If we disconnect the Q1's collector, its base-emitter "diode" is not buffered and the entire input current flows through Q1 and Q2 bases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frSgEE.png)</sup>

Since the base resistance is significant, the voltage is higher and Q2 even saturates.

[image: _STEP 4_1]

**Ordinary diode**. Here, in contrast to the previous one, Vbe is lower...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy3yQW.png)</sup>

... but the curve is non-linear again.

[image: STEP 4_2]

So it is worth putting an *active diode* on the input.